# "error: pathspec '....' did not match any file(s) known to git" on bare repository

Tags: git, gogs

## Set up

- Local normal repository (`git init`), `git version 2.17.0.windows.1`
- Bare repository (`git init --bare`) on a separate server `git version 2.7.4`
- [Gogs](http://gogs.io) as a UI to the bare repository

## Problem

This has been working fine for a couple of years, few hitches.  However, I've created a pull request on Gogs and tried to merge it, and it's come up with a 500 error, and a message

> An error has occurred : git checkout 'development': error: pathspec 'development' did not match any file(s) known to git.

(`development` is the branch I'm trying to merge to)

I tried re-creating the repository - created a new, blank repository, pushed all the branches there again, and tried the merge again - got the same error.

The branch definitely exists on both the local & remote repositories.  Is there a way to fix the problem?

Comment: Can a branch be checked out on a bare repo?

Comment: Good point, I don't think it can.  Odd that it should try to do that, really ..

Comment: Consider cloning the bare repo somewhere else on your disk and try your stuff their.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to have been fixed in Gogs `0.11.63` (maybe even in `0.11.53`, I didn't test that one). You might want to try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might be a Gogs-specific problem/bug.  I've downgraded to the previous version, and the problem's gone away.  Will keep this open in case someone finds a better solution ...